# No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'imageByPreparingForDisplay' AND 'imageByPreparingThumbnailOfSize'

Tags: react-native, uiimage

[image]

No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'imageByPreparingForDisplay'  AND 'imageByPreparingThumbnailOfSize'

[image: [1]: https://i.strong textstack.imgur.com/VNXDh.png]

Comment: Maybe you need to update XCode?

Comment: currently my XCode Version 12.4 (12D4e)

Comment: @PareshChavda did you figure this one out?